# Docker container output does no update last line of its stdout and instead spams

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running a docker container via `docker-compose up` (although similar things happen via `docker run`) and getting too much output. Specifically the webpack npm package spams the console like bellow.

```
alarm-fe               | <s> [webpack.Progress] 86% before chunk ids
alarm-fe               | <s> [webpack.Progress] 86% before chunk ids NamedChunksPlugin
alarm-fe               | <s> [webpack.Progress] 86% chunk id optimization
alarm-fe               | <s> [webpack.Progress] 87% after chunk id optimization
alarm-fe               | <s> [webpack.Progress] 87% record modules
alarm-fe               | <s> [webpack.Progress] 87% record modules RecordIdsPlugin
alarm-fe               | <s> [webpack.Progress] 87% record chunks
alarm-fe               | <s> [webpack.Progress] 87% record chunks RecordIdsPlugin
alarm-fe               | <s> [webpack.Progress] 88% hashing
```

Normally, the `<s>` would not show up and new updated completion percentage would just replace the last line. How do I make the container do the same thing?

Comment: Please share your dockerfile and code snippet relevant for your question